# Manually setting path to a cshtml file and ignoring the MVC Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Let's say i have 2 files located in the same folder.

/Test/View.cshtml

```
<h1>File that needs to be loaded in to a string</h1>
```

/Test/Content.cs

```
public class Content {
    public string GetView()
    {
        Return View("/Test/View.cshtml",someModel)
    }
}
```

It should not cair about the RouteData from Web.Config

The point of doing this is, so that i am able to retrieve the GetView and use it elsewhere.

I know this question and approch is wierd but i am in a uniq situation developeing a CMS system, so i really need something like this.

How could i achieve this :)?

---

**Update: Explanation**

_Layout.cshtml

This file has no RenderBody as it normally has. Instead it has different Areas like this one.

```
@{
    Render r = new Render("Content");
}
@r.Print()
```

Each area are printing out different modules, fx: a newsletter or a gallery. And for that to be possible this is done:

```
public interface IModule
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    string View();
}


public class ModuleList
{
    public List<IModule> Modules = new List<IModule>();

    public ModuleList()
    {
        Modules.Add(new ContentView() { Name = "Content" });
        Modules.Add(new GalleryView() { Name = "Gallery" });
        Modules.Add(new NewsletterView() { Name = "Newsletter" });
    }
}
```

And here is is the ContentView Class (One of many Modules)

```
public class ContentView: IModule
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    DbModulesDataContext db = new DbModulesDataContext();

    public string View()
    {
        var q = (from c in db.mContents
                 where c.Id == Id
                 select c).FirstOrDefault();
        return ("<h1>"+q.Html+"</h1>");
    }
}
```

As you can see right now the html is inline with the c# but i want it the other way around. (i want the View() to work together with a cshtml file)

Does it make a little more sence now?

Comment: Either you use the MVC lib or you don't...  That GetView() method does not seem worth re-using. And it won't work.

Comment: No i realize that it wont work. It was just illustrate what i want. It's to long a story if i am to exmplain why i need it, but i really do need to load a cshtml file into a variable wich i can use as i want.

Comment: You could send the name of a Partial View.

Comment: Could you show me how the method would look if i where to do that :)?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  How exactly are planning to return a model that doesn't exist?  How exactly are you trying to use a method `View()` that doesn't exist in your class either?  You need to explain what you're trying to do more clearly.

Comment: Allright :) I'll try! I'll update the question i a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found my solution!

It's right there!
http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Thank you for trying though :)